# Populate Adjacent Value in Pandas Column When String is Duplicated

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to overwrite the value named in a column called 'Group' when the value in a column called 'Keyword' is a duplicate with the adjacent value.

For example, because the string 'commercial office cleaning services' is duplicated, I'd like to overwrite the adjacent column to 'commercial cleaning services'.

**Example Data**

[image]

**Desired Output**

[image]

**Minimum Reproducible Example**

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ["commercial cleaning services", "commercial cleaning services"],
    ["commercial office cleaning services", "commercial cleaning services"],
    ["janitorial cleaning services", "commercial cleaning services"],
    ["commercial office services", "commercial cleaning"],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Keyword", "Group"])
print(df)
```

I'm fairly new to pandas and not sure where to start, I've reached a dead end Googling and searching stackoverflow.

Comment: your data still doesn't match the images you uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) :

```
#is the keyword duplicated ?
m = df['Keyword'].duplicated()

df['Group'] = df['Group'].mask(m).ffill()
```

##### # Output:

```
print(df)

                               Keyword                         Group
0         commercial cleaning services  commercial cleaning services
1  commercial office cleaning services  commercial cleaning services
2         janitorial cleaning services  commercial cleaning services
3  commercial office cleaning services  commercial cleaning services
```

*NB: The reproducible example does not match the image of the input (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPWPa.png)*

Comment: Thanks for this, I've just edited my minimum reproducible example to match the image. 

I think my example may have been too minimal, as I always need to return the adjacent cell for all duplicated. (Not a fixed string). It'll always be the value in the group column. 

Hope that makes sense, and really appreciate the answer.

Comment: It still does not match the image but I updated my answer anyway ;)

Comment: You absolute legend. I've been pulling my hair out. Really appreciate it!